# Ant publish stuff to different locations

Tags: java, deployment, ant, build, copy

I have a java project and an ANT script to build and then distribute the project to other projects with a simple copy command.

I would like to only name the place where to copy to files to once in the header of the ant script, and not have an explicit copy-task for every project that is dependent on this project.

I can't find anything like arrays in ANT, so what would be the cleanest way of distributing something to multiple directories?

Comment: I agree with Dave. Sounds like you should be publishing to a Maven repository manager (like Nexus or Artifactory) and then let other projects pull your build's output as dependencies. Check it out, you'll never look back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what I commented under Martin's answer, I'd like to post my version of solution as another choice. And I am using property names from Martin's answer to make it clear.

```
<target name="deploy" >
    <property name="dest.dirs" value="/dir/one,/dir/two,/dir/thr/ee" />
    <for list="${dest.dirs}" param="dest.dir" parallel="true" delimiter="," >
        <sequential>
            <copy todir="@{dest.dir}" >
                <fileset dir="${srd.dir}" />
            </copy>
        </sequential>
    </for>
</target>
```

Please note that "for" is an Ant-Contrib task, and it's using Macrodef in the back so you should use @{} to refer to "dest.dir"; the "dest.dirs" will be splited into a list (maybe String[]) by delimiter. Here we use comma to split it (and the default value to delimiter is comma). I also added "parallel" to make it copy files to all the "dest.dirs" at same time, however, if the project to copy is large, you should delete "parallel".

Please check http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/for.html
and http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/foreach.html for more information.

Comment: seems to be the most straight forward solution

Comment: @oers Still need to download ant-contrib jar, put it in the classpath, and add a "taskdef" :P

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you have many viable options: the `copy` task accepts only a single directory.

1. Create your own copy task that takes a list of directories.
2. Exec a script/program that does the copying.
3. Have the subprojects do a pull.

I'm really hesitant about having a project push to other projects, because that makes the assumption that those projects will work with the newly-pushed code. IMO the "sub-"projects should be making the decision if they want the new version or not.

To me this sounds more like a dependency management issue, better handled with Ivy/Maven/Gradle (or other Maven-alike).

All that said, it sounds like you'd want to do option 1, create a custom Ant task that accepts a list of destination directories; it might be pretty easy to just extend the existing copy task to get all its functionality--just add a "todirs" property.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using a [`scriptmapper`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html#script-mapper) in your copy task with `enablemultiplemappings` true.

First, list the target directories in a property and create a `filelist` from it.  (You could use a dirset, but the [API for filelist](http://api.dpml.net/ant/1.6.5/org/apache/tools/ant/types/FileList.html) is simpler.)  Then run the copy, with the scriptmapper setting up the multiple destinations.

```
<property name="dest.dirs" value="/dir/one,/dir/two,/dir/thr/ee" />    
<filelist id="dests" dir="/" files="${dest.dirs}" />

<copy todir="/" enablemultiplemappings="yes">
    <fileset dir="${srd.dir}" />
    <scriptmapper language="javascript">
        <![CDATA[
            // Obtain a reference to the filelist
            var filelist = project.getReference( "dests" );

            var dests = filelist.getFiles( project );
            for ( var i = 0; i < dests.length; i++ )
            {
                self.addMappedName( dests[i] + "/" + source );
            }
        ]]>
    </scriptmapper>
</copy>
```

Comment: Could ANT-contrib tasks "foreach" and "for" also help? Like the dest.dirs in your example, using comma to split it and do copy for each one in "foreach" or "for". In my environment, "foreach" is used to deploy Grinder to different machines.