# Ant How to copy a single file in multiple directories

Tags: ant, copy, directory

I have a question about copying only one file in multiple directories during build process. I know there are similiar issues that already have been asked, but I don't get it. I am a newbie.
I have the following folderstructure:

root folder (with file to be copied)

---folder 1 with android project 1 (subfolder of root folder)

---folder 2 with another project 2 ("")

---folder 3 with project 3         ("")

I know this sounds simple, but in the manual http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html there is only the way "Copy a set of files to a directory" and not "Copy a file to a set of directories". Sure, I can do this by hand, meaning:
copy file to project 1, copy file to project 2...but this is not what I want and the build.xml code is getting very large, because I have about 30 projects.

Thank you very much.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8105355/ant-publish-stuff-to-different-locations/8106295#8106295

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224194/ant-copy-a-list-of-files-evenly-across-multiple-folders/14224742#14224742